# Different profile page by role

Tags: customization, functions, author

I'm trying to set it so that when you view somebody's profile page you see a different template based on their role. So, everybody gets a regular "profile" page but if your also a author you also get a special "editor" page as well.

Normally in Wordpress you get...

www.mysite.com/author/person1

but what I want is...

www.mysite.com/profile/person1
www.mysite.com/profile/person2
www.mysite.com/editor/person2

Below is what I've got so far in my functions.php file but the line that sets variable $curauth doesn't seem to work here. But it does work in my loop.php file???

```
function change_author_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
    var_dump($curauth);
    if ( !get_user_role( 'subscriber', $curauth->ID ) ) {
        $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'editor';
    } else {
        $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'profile';
    }

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init','change_author_permalinks');
```

Answer (score 1):

i needed something similar to this so i added a rewrite rule to the same author.php file and there i added a redirect based on the user role, so to put this in your use case:

First redirect editor to your theme author.php file by adding this rewrite rule

```
function my_rewrite_rules_098( $wp_rewrite ) {
  $newrules = array();
  $new_rules['editor/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]';
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules','my_rewrite_rules_098');
```

Next create a function to check the user role, say in your functions.php file:

```
function user_has_role( $roles_to_check = array(), $user_id ) {

  if( ! $roles_to_check ) return FALSE;
  if( ! $user_id ) return FALSE;

  $user = new WP_User( $user_id ); // $user->roles

  return in_array( $roles_to_check, $user->roles, FALSE );
}
```

then in your author.php theme file at the top add this:

```
if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) {
    $curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);
}else{
    $curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
}
//check user role  
$user_role_exists = user_has_role( array('Author'),$curauth->ID; );
if ($user_role_exists && isset(get_query_var('editor'))){
    //either rediret to a different editor.php template file 
    //or include it here something like:
    include('editor.php');
    exit;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hmmm I'm still getting the same result in $curauth = bool(false). Should $author_name and $author be set as global variables?

Comment: not in functions.php only on author.php